# WAVGAT Arduino Pro mini I2C pins?

Tags: arduino, i2c, pins, oled

I'm trying to hook up an OLED display using I2C communication to my Arduino Pro Mini clone(with ATmega 168, 16MHz) from WAVGAT but I can't figure out where the I2C pins are on the Arduino.

Comment: I2C pins on the Arduino or the OLED display?  if display, which one are you using?  They are not all the same.

Comment: on the arduino.

Comment: So what does the Wavgat manual say about it?

Comment: I can't find the manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "official" Arduino Pro Mini pinout is:

[image: Arduino Pro Mini Pinout from https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2018/06/introduction-to-arduino-pro-mini.html]

So your I2C pins SHOULD BE at the A4 and A5 positions.  There doesn't seem to be any information on the WAVGAT model.  But that's common with Chinese knock-offs.  You get what you get and may have to improvise.

Comment: it worked, thanks